# replacing several different characters in a string java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a string from a file that I read and I want to remove contents of that string. An example would be like this: `PN ,D2 ,R2 , F ,Di , B ,Ri ,Fi` What I want to do is to remove all the commas and if there is more than one space between each 1 or two characters like `R2 , F` I would want to remove the extra space and comma. So far I have been able to remove some other contents in the string but can't seem to be able to remove the commas and extra spaces.

```
String cleanerLine = reverseLine.replaceAll("PN ,", "");
        System.out.print("Solution: " + cleanerLine);
```

The output is like this: 
`Solution: D2 ,R2 , F ,Di , B ,Ri ,Fi`

Comment: But here you also remove `"PN"`. Is that desired behavior?

Comment: yes that is what i wanted to do as well but I can't seem to remove the extra spaces if there are some and the commas. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: You may remove all the whitespace first then replace the commas with single whitespace. Bad?

Comment: @ErdemE.: but once you remove the commas, you might generate multiple whitespace, like `" , "` will collapse to `"  "` (two spaces).

Comment: Can you please provide the output you want to achieve from the example given?

Comment: `D2 B D F L2 U2` @Izruo

Comment: You may use `.replaceAll("(?:PN)?(\\s)*,\\s*", "$1")`

Comment: how do I learn that regex. It looks appealing but I have no idea how to learn all the symbols and what they mean. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Here is a [link](https://regex101.com/r/vMMQZ2/1) where you may read its explanation. It might not be really what you want, just a suggestion.

Comment: This post has got me worried. It's _not important to know where_ extra spaces are in relation to a comma you're removing anyway. Is it? No, it isn't. You don't want to remove comma's _without_ spaces around them do you? No, you don't. `ab,cd,ef,gh,ij` becomes `abcdefghi` and why have spaces at all if so. And kind of a <space> is important right? Apparently. Forget all the junk, use a solution given your constraints. Find `(?:[ ,]*PN[ ,]*)|[ ,]+` Replace with `<space>`

Comment: And if you don't think _PN_ is unique, use this instead Find `(?:[ ,]*(?<!\w)PN(?!\w)[ ,]*)|[ ,]+` Replace `<space>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`String.replaceAll(String,String)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) method takes as **first argument a *regular expression*. So you could write something like:

```
String cleanerLine = reverseLine.replaceAll("PN ,","")
                                .replaceAll(",", "")
                                .replaceAll(" {2,}"," ");
```

The `" {2,}"` is a regular expression that matches with all "*two or more spaces*".

When `reverseLine` is:

```
String reverseLine = "PN ,D2 ,R2 , F ,Di , B ,Ri ,Fi";
System.out.println(reverseLine.replaceAll("PN ,","").replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll(" {2,}"," "));
```

it produces:

```
D2 R2 F Di B Ri Fi
```

Comment: could that also include the removed `PN, `'s I was removing?

Comment: It works thanks :) I will accept the answer once enough time has passed